# propagation of "-g" in shared libraries with gcc

Tags: c, linker, gdb, debug-symbols

I have the a program `abc`.  `abc` uses the library `def` and `def` in turn includes a library `ghi`.

Now, `libghi.so` is compiled and linked using `gcc -g`.  `libdef.so` is *also* compiled and linked using `gcc -g`.  However, `abc` *isn't* linked with `-g`.

The question is, if I debug `abc` with `gdb` should I be able to see the symbols in `def` and `ghi`?

The project is pretty big and compilation takes a few hours, which is why I'm asking before testing it myself.

Comment: Does abc contain the main entry point?

Comment: You could test it with a small example code instead of the real application if you are curious.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you will be able to, though it may be a bit difficult to use them without the debug info in the calling application.